# My service is hosted on Google App Engine and it is behind Cloudflare CDN. How can I check my server's ssl cert details?

Tags: cloudflare

I cannot use CF origin ssl cert in GAE because GAE does not accept it.

I have to purchase ssl cert from other CA and apply it to my service. The old ssl cert is going to expire in a week time. How can I verify that I have successfully applied the new ssl? In browser i can only see the Cloudflare-issued SSL cert because my service is served via Cloudflare CDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can check the SSL cert with the following command this way:

```
curl -vIs4 https://<hostname>/ --resolve <hostname>:443:<origin_ip>
```

Let's say the domain is `mycompany.com`. Since it is hosted on GAE, the origin_ip will be that of `ghs.googlehosted.com`

The final command is:

```
curl -vIs4 https://mycompany.com/ --resolve mycompany.com:443:172.217.25.179
```

Part of the output:

```
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: OU=Domain Control Validated; OU=Gandi Standard Wildcard SSL; CN=*.mycompany.com
*  start date: Apr 11 00:00:00 2019 GMT
*  expire date: Apr 11 23:59:59 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "www.mycompany.com" matched cert's "*.mycompany.com"
*  issuer: C=FR; ST=Paris; L=Paris; O=Gandi; CN=Gandi Standard SSL CA 2
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the clients isn't connected to yours server. They connect to cloudflare which serves the certificate then cloudflare connects to your server to request resources and verifies certificate served by you.

[image]
[image]
You will need to upload custom certificate to cloudflare which require at least bussiness plan 200$/month. Settings can be found under `crypto` tab in part named `Edge certificates`

Or remove cloudflare.